# how to get mysql server to stop starting as slave

Tags: ubuntu, replication, mysql, master-slave

I have a an ubuntu we server running mysql 5.1.  Previously I had this server set up as a slave for replication.  Now I and switching rolls for this server and I do not need it to be a slave anymore.  **The problem is** that right now, every time the mysql is restarted, it starts into slave mode, and when I run commands like this:

```
mysql < mysql_dump_file.sql
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1198 (HY000) at line 22: This operation cannot be performed with a running slave; run STOP SLAVE first
```

Of course I can run the `stop slave;` command in mysql and it fixes the issue, but when I restart the server the problem comes back.

Previously for the slave configuration, I had added the following lines in the my.cnf file:

```
port=3306
log-bin
server-id=2
master-host=(ip of master)
master-user=repl
master-password=slavepass
master-port=3306
replicate_do_db=(db to replicate)
```

Now I have removed all these lines and restarted, and the db automatically starts into slave mode still.  I am trying to configure the mysql so that it will NOT start up in slave mode.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RESET SLAVE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reset-slave.html) to restart slave from start or to stop the replication just remove master.info and relay-log.info files manually.

```
RESET SLAVE;
```

It deletes the master.info and relay-log.info files, all the relay log files, and starts a new relay log file.